# Select Query with Multiple Rows in Join Table in collection in Magento

Tags: php, mysql, magento, join, zend-framework

How Do I do Select Statement in _preparecollection in Magento if the table I joined in the Main table has 2 rows with 1 parent ID.

Tables I have now.

Table 1(Main Table)
[image]

Table 2(sales_flat_invoice_comment)
[image]

My Current Prepare Collection

```
$collection = Mage::getResourceModel($this->_getCollectionClass());
$collection->getSelect()->join( array('a'=> mgmx_sales_flat_invoice_comment), 'a.parent_id = main_table.entity_id', array('a.comment'));
$this->setCollection($collection);
return parent::_prepareCollection();
```

This query, in echoed will be like this

> SELECT `main_table`.*, `a`.`comment` 
>   FROM `mgmx_sales_flat_invoice_grid` AS `main_table` 
>   INNER JOIN `mgmx_sales_flat_invoice_comment` AS `a` 
>   ON a.parent_id = main_table.entity_id

But it will return an error if this query finds more than 1 row in table 2.

What I want is for something like the one below

[image]

With | as a delimiter.

How Can I achieved this in the _prepareCollection of Magento.

Answer (score 0):

you have to group by the `entity_id` and then use `group_concat` to create your comment column. You can define a separator in the group by.

The concatenated column has a limit in length. So depending on the length of your single comments and the number of comments it might happen that you do not get all of them in the result.

I hope this helps with solving your problem.

Comment: I did that on Mysql already. My last question Sir is how to convert it to a zend framework query

Answer (score 0):

To get the group_concat loading in the zend framework you can define it using the Zend_Db_Expr object

Something like

```php
$collection->getSelect()->join(
    array('a'=> new Zend_Db_Expr('GROUP_CONCAT(mgmx_sales_flat_invoice_comment)')), 
    'a.parent_id = main_table.entity_id', 
    array('a.comment')
);
```

Which is handy to know about whenever you need to do custom database functions inside the zend framework.